# Calculate prediction interval for SAR model (errorsarlm function in R)

Tags: prediction, autocorrelation, spatial, autoregressive, prediction-interval

I would like to predict prediction interval for a SAR model (function errorsarlm in R - package spdep). While the function predict.lm allows to set interval='prediction' parameter to predict the upper and lower boundary of predictions, the function predict.sarlm does not. 
Is it because it is incorrect to estimate the prediction interval of a SAR or simply because it hasn't implemented?
Is it possible to calculate those prediction intervals manually? 
Below a replicable example:

```
library(spdep)
data(oldcol)
lw <- nb2listw(COL.nb, style="W") #listw object
mod <- errorsarlm(CRIME ~ INC + HOVAL, data=COL.OLD, lw) #SAR model
predict(mod, COL.OLD) #here I would like to get prediction intervals
```